# mp4 video exported from x265 does not play

Tags: encoding

I use x265 to encode a video and the output is mp4. Unfortunately, this file is not playable by any program.

The input video is yuv if that matters.

Do you know which the problem might be?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What player are you trying to use ? does it play in another app like VLC, Quicktime, etc. Are you using a Apple Mac or Windows PC ?

Comment: I use a windows PC. I tried VLC, Quicktime and media player and non of them can play it. No, it does not play anywhere right now.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the x265 codec needs to be installed for the App you are using to play the file with.

VLC does support x265 with a dd on codec but it seems the link on there site is broken
https://www.videolan.org/developers/x265.html which is not very useful right now.

there are some other players out there doing a quick Google brought up some results but I dont have a x265 file to play with to test them.

if you exported the file, have you tried exporting it again to see if the same issue happens ?

Comment: Thank you for your response! What is a dd on codec? Yes, I've tried exporting the file once again and the problem still remains. Using -r parameter, I managed to get a yuv reconstructed file which in playable using YUViewer.

Comment: "an add on codec" sorry for my sloppy typing

Answer (score 0):

VLC is usually quite slow to update their version of ffmpeg.  A recent build of [mpv](http://mpv.io/) should do well.  It's been playing h.265 for me since well before this question was asked.

Also note that Adam's answer is not quite right.  x265 is an encoder, and doesn't include a decoder.  FFMpeg's hevc decoder (in libavcodec, aka lavc) is the main Free Software implementation that everything uses.

IDK if VLC's current release plays h.265 (at all / well), or if you need a nightly build.  (assuming you want to use VLC, and not mpv / mplayer2 / mplayer).